# iTunes Connect: Invalid Swift Support

Tags: ios, swift, app-store-connect, testflight, xcode7

Ever since upgrading to Xcode 7, I have not been able to upload any builds to TestFlight or iTunes. I can build the app and it appears to upload, but a few minutes after uploading I receive an email which states:

> Dear developer,
>       We have discovered one or more issues with your recent delivery for “MyApp”. To process your delivery, the following issues must be corrected:
>       Invalid Swift Support - The files libswiftCoreAudio.dylib, libswiftCoreLocation.dylib, libswiftEventKit.dylib, libswiftWebKit.dylib, libswiftCoreMedia.dylib, libswiftAVFoundation.dylib don’t match /Payload/MyApp.app/Frameworks/libswiftCoreAudio.dylib, /Payload/MyApp.app/Frameworks/libswiftCoreLocation.dylib, /Payload/MyApp.app/Frameworks/libswiftEventKit.dylib, /Payload/MyApp.app/Frameworks/libswiftWebKit.dylib, /Payload/MyApp.app/Frameworks/libswiftCoreMedia.dylib, /Payload/MyApp.app/Frameworks/libswiftAVFoundation.dylib.
>
> Make sure the files are correct, rebuild your app, and resubmit it. Don’t apply post-processing to /Payload/MyApp.app/Frameworks/libswiftCoreAudio.dylib, /Payload/MyApp.app/Frameworks/libswiftCoreLocation.dylib, /Payload/MyApp.app/Frameworks/libswiftEventKit.dylib, /Payload/MyApp.app/Frameworks/libswiftWebKit.dylib, /Payload/MyApp.app/Frameworks/libswiftCoreMedia.dylib, /Payload/MyApp.app/Frameworks/libswiftAVFoundation.dylib.
>       Once these issues have been corrected, you can then redeliver the corrected binary.
>       Regards,
>       The App Store team

These appear to be native Swift libraries. Has anyone else occurred this or could anyone help me understand what could have caused this after the Xcode upgrade?